# How to get two separate procs on one row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have set up two procs to add data to the same table. The reason I did two procs instead of one is at the request of management. Currently though, it adds the data to two separate rows, but I'd prefer them to be on the same row if possible. Both procs bring in today's date, so I figure that would be the best way to do it, but I can't get it to work. Here's the first proc

```
INSERT INTO [BI_20200605_AllLoansDash] ([DATE], ALLMortgagesCount, AllMortgagesDistinctMemberCount,   MortgageBalances)
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS Date,  COUNT(IIF (EMC.MC_PRIN_BAL > 0 AND EMC.MC_EXT_DROP_DATE IS NULL, EMC.MC_BORROWER_1_MBR_NBR, null) ) AS ALLMortgagesCount, 
COUNT(DISTINCT IIF(EMC.MC_PRIN_BAL > 0 AND EMC.MC_EXT_DROP_DATE IS NULL, EMC.MC_BORROWER_1_MBR_NBR, null) ) AS AllMortgagesDistinctMemberCount, 
SUM(IIF(EMC.MC_PRIN_BAL > 0 AND EMC.MC_EXT_DROP_DATE IS NULL, EMC.MC_PRIN_BAL, null))As MortgageBalances
FROM EMC
WHERE EMC.MC_EXT_DROP_DATE IS NULL
```

And here's the second proc.

```
INSERT INTO [BI_20200605_AllLoansDash] ([DATE], ALLCreditCardCount, AllCreditCardDistinctMemberCount,  AllNewCreditCards ,  CreditCardsClosed,  CreditCardBalances)
SELECT 
CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS Date,  COUNT(IIF (ECC.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL AND ECC.BLOCK_CODE = ' ', ECC.SAVINGS_ACCT_NBR, null) ) AS ALLCreditCardCount, 
COUNT(DISTINCT IIF(ECC.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL AND ECC.BLOCK_CODE = ' ', ECC.SAVINGS_ACCT_NBR, null) ) AS AllCreditCardDistinctMemberCount, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) = ECC.Open_Date AND ECC.BLOCK_CODE = ' ' THEN ECC.SAVINGS_ACCT_NBR ELSE NULL END) AS AllNewCreditCards,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) = ECC.CLOSE_DATE AND ECC.BLOCK_CODE = ' ' THEN ECC.SAVINGS_ACCT_NBR ELSE NULL END) AS CreditCardsClosed,
SUM(IIF(ECC.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL AND ECC.BLOCK_CODE = ' ', ECC.CURRENT_BAL, null))As CreditCardBalances

FROM ECC
WHERE ECC.BLOCK_CODE = ' '
```

Comment: That's what `INSERT` does, it add a new row; It literally "inserts" a row. If you want to change a row, that's `UPDATE`; which "updates" the values in a row.

Comment: Ahh geez, I feel like an idiot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An insert must create a row, so if you wish to have two separate stored procedures with inserts, two rows will be created. If you would like the aggregated data to be on one row, you have two choices. The first option is preferable as it is cleaner and keeps the logic for your batch job together for future maintenance(when management inevitably asks for another piece of data):

1) One S.Proc. that joins your two queries before inserting in to the table.

2) Have one S.Proc. perform the insert and the second S.Proc. perform an update using some shared identifier to find the existing row to update with new information. This will cause a dependency between the two S.Proc.s where the insert S.Proc. must run before the update S.Proc. Due to this dependancy, this solution is sub-optimal to option 1.